# Steps to use hibernate in a spring 3 mvc application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Can someone outline the steps required to get hibernate working with spring mvc.

I've seen EntityDao's that basically inherit from a GenericDAo.

The generic Dao has basic operations like GetAll, GetByID, Save, Delete, etc.

And inside their methods they use:

```
getHibernateTemplate
```

So basically the Session has to be wired up in a bean, and mysql settings have to be set.

I find the spring documentation to be a little confusing: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic components are:

- Something to configure and create the Hibernate `SessionFactory`. This is typically done by  the `LocalSessionFactoryBean`, as used in the example in the link you posted. This exposes a Spring-managed bean that implements the Hibernate `SessionFactory` interface.
- Typically, you then have one or more DAO beans which are injected with the `SessionFactory`. In many cases, the simplest thing to do here is to extend the convenient `HibernateDaoSupport` class, which has a `sessionFactory` property. `HibernateDaoSupport` proves a `getHibernateTemplate()` method, which gets a Hibernate `Session` from the `SessionFactory` and wraps it in a `HibernateTemplate` object, which provides various convenience methods for doing common Hibernate operations, and is generally more useful than the raw `Session` interface.

Using this pattern, there is very little direct interaction between application code and the Hibernate API itself, its mostly done though s Spring intermediate layer. Some would call this a good thing, others would rather Spring stayed out of the way. This is a perfectly good alternative - there's nothing to stop you injecting your bean with `SessionFactory` and using the Hibernate API directly. The `HibernateDaoSupport` and `HibernateTemplate` classes are there purely as a convenience.

Comment: great thanks.  So my GenericDao will extend HibernateDaoSupport.  And HibernateDaoSupport has to be wired up in a bean to set its SessionFactory.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way. If you don't want to use HibernateDaoSupport then you could directly inject SessionFactory into your DAO classes. This avoids tying you down to Spring classes.

Refer this for example - [Spring Doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight)

This shows how to use Hibernate APIs directly.

Hope that helps.